# Concatenate Rows at different levels of a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

[Click Image to View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFRll.jpg)

In Above Image link is a datatable and with rows highlighted in blue border needs to be concatenate , as we can see the Project Ids are same but present at different levels in datatable

How to concatenate these 2 levels and aggregate it or bring the down 2 rows and append it with above rows with same project ID.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter to those rows?  Concatenating datarows makes little sense

Comment: Is this a query? (in SQL ?) . How are you obtaining the records.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do and what tools you are using to do it. As per the `datatable` tag, this is an ambiguous term in .NET so it requires more explanation. Please also show the code of what you have tried, any references you used, etc. Are you using Excel, SQL Server, LINQ, System.Data.DataTable?

Comment: " but present at different levels in datatable", do you meant *they are not ordered by Project Id*?

Comment: there is no issue with the Datatable as we can see the picture link but the the Project Ids are meant to come together for eg. ST-2014 , some of it is coming up as show inside blue border and some in blue border highlighted at the end rows of datatable. I want to show them in a stack means together.

Comment: @jedgard Yes it coming through a stored procedure

Comment: "I want to show them" doesn't explain much. Please edit your question and inform us what you would like to achieve. Be very specific.

Comment: Can we see the stored procedure? - might just be an Order By missing

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes they are ordered but still set of rows with that project id shows differently

Comment: `they are ordered`  Ok, but ordered by what???  Show the SQL

Comment: Also looks like they are ordered by  MODDATE while it should be by PROJECTID

Comment: sorry folks i did miss the order by Project ID :

Comment: @jedgard Yes you are right : ON SUBSTRING(C.NTACCOUNT, CHARINDEX('\', C.NTACCOUNT) + 1, LEN(C.NTACCOUNT))  =      
   SUBSTRING(A.[ASSIGNEDTO], CHARINDEX('\', A.[ASSIGNEDTO]) + 1, LEN(A.[ASSIGNEDTO]))                   
  where a.status <> 'Not Received' ORDER BY A.PROJECTID,A.MODDATE

Comment: cool i am glad that worked!

Comment: You can mark my answer if you want and that worked :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing a Order By ProjectID based on how the table shows. Apparently it is only ordering by MODDATE.